# Adding values to be used by another attribute ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to use two values, in two different tables, to be used as a total in a third table.

For instance:

1. table `accommodation` and `flight`
2. Add value from `acc_price` with value from `flight_price`
3. Add those values up to be used in table `reservation.reservation_total`

Things I've tried;

---

```
SELECT  F.FLI_PRICE + AC.ACC_PRICEPN
INTO    R.SUBTOTAL
FROM    HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R, FLIGHT F, ACCOMMODATION AC;
```

---

```
UPDATE HOLIDAY_RESERVATION HR
SET SUBTOTAL = (SELECT SUM (T.PRICE) FROM ( SELECT ACC_PRICEPN PRICE FROM ACCOMMODATION A
WHERE A.ACC_ID = HR.ACC_ID)

UNION ALL
SELECT FLI_PRICE PRICE FROM FLIGHT F1
WHERE HR.IN_FLIGHT_ID = F1.FLI_ID

UNION ALL
SELECT FLI_PRICE PRICE FROM FLIGHT F2
WHERE HR.OUT_FLIGHT_ID = F2.FLI_ID
) T
);
```

---

Comment: Its my first time doing sql, but i think i need to do a select sum with two inner joins and select into the reservation total and then have a sequence auto do it for each row and perhaps a trigger? but this all sounds too complex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SELECT INTO` statement of `PL-SQL`....This will definately solve your problem............

Answer (score 0):

why not add them two value directly in one sql

```
select acc_price+flight_price from accomodation,flight
```

Answer (score 0):

By "Add those values up to be used in table reservation.reservation_total" do you mean you want to insert the added values in the reservation_total column of reservation ? 
If so, you can use:

```
insert into reservation(rowid,reservation_total) values (id,select acc_price +
flight_price from accomodation, flight where <some condition> )
```

Comment: select into suggested by @akash88 is a better option though.

Comment: I have tried `SELECT  F.FLI_PRICE + AC.ACC_PRICEPN
INTO    R.SUBTOTAL
FROM    HOLIDAY_RESERVATION R, FLIGHT F, ACCOMMODATION AC;` but it doesnt work

Comment: Dont you have to put any condition ? if you could tell me the exact question, as given in the homework and the schema of these three tables I would be able to help you